# What is the trick in the derivation? Density of a complicated function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, derivatives

Through one of the proofs I found a problem that really cannot solve. Imagine some density function f(x). Now, imagine that the argument is a function of the form x+c(f'(x)/f(x)). Therefore, the density might be rewritten as

$$
\int f\left[x+c\left({f'(x) \over f(x)}\right)\right] dx,
$$

where c is some constant.

Now what is the trick to show that the expression above is equal to
$$
\int f(x) + c f''(x) dx
$$
???

Comment: Canonically this can't be true; consider the case where $f(x)\approx x$ (over some range and scaled appropriately to make it a density function), so $f'$ is some constant and $f''$ is identically 0.

Comment: what if we add the assumption that the density is twice differentaible?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference - you can 'staple together' the corners with infinitely-differentiable functions of exponential falloff as small as you want and still be sure that it won't affect the behavior at most points $x$ (since $\frac{f'}{f}$ won't generically fall into the zones of strange behavior).

Comment: I see now your point. But still isn't there a way around? I suppose that the case when the distribution is very narrow is one side of the story. How about smoother distributions?

Comment: I got the small mistake, that could cause the confusion. I should add the integral signs as it is right now. Without the integration this does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty straightforward up to the second order Taylor approximation. We know that density f has some distribution F. Substitute x=y-cf'(y)/f(y). Hence:
$$
F'(y) = f\left(x+c{f'(x) \over f(x)}\right)\left(1 + c {f''(x)f(x) - f'(x)f'(x) \over f(x)f(x)}\right) \\ \approx f(x) + c {f'(x)f'(x) \over f(x)} + f(x)\left(c {f''(x)f(x) - f'(x)f'(x) \over f(x)f(x)}\right) \\
\approx f(x) + c f''(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty straightforward and is a resounding "NO". Consider $f(x)=x+a$, then
$$
f\left[x+c\left({f'(x) \over f(x)}\right)\right]=x+a+\frac{c}{x+a}\ne x+a=f(x) + c f''(x).
$$