# Trick in integration with Taylor expansion

Tags: probability, statistics, ordinary-differential-equations, integration

I am struggling with the expression of the LHS of the following equation.

[image]

The RHS is just the Taylor expansion of the first function around point y and the differentiation wrp to the argument y.

How to prove that it is equal up to the

$$
(f(y)-cf''(y))dy
$$
Any ideas?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322969/what-is-the-trick-in-the-derivation-density-of-a-complicated-function

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is
$$
f\cdot\left(1-c\frac{\color{red}{(f')^2}}{f^2}\right)\cdot\left(1-c\frac{\color{blue}{f''f}-\color{red}{(f')^2}}{f^2}\right)+O(c^2)=f\cdot\left(1-c\frac{\color{blue}{f''f}}{f^2}\right)+O(c^2),
$$
and the RHS of this identity simplifies to $f-c\color{blue}{f''}+O(c^2)$.